# pruebas unitarias a código con pytest ó unittest

Tags: python, pruebas-unitarias, unittest

Hola estoy realizando pruebas unitarias para este código pero no conozco este tema me podrían dar una mano por favor?
El código lo que hace es leer el archivo csv, verificar los datos, si son strings reemplazarlos por ceros para luego realizar cálculos del detaframe (gastos e ingresos durante un año) como sumar los datos negativos, sumar datos positivos, calcular la media o promedio para cada columna(que son los meses del año), y no se si podra realizar las pruebas unitarias con el framework pytest o unittest, e visto tutoriales sobre esto pero los ejemplos son básicos no e logrado implementarlo a este código.

```
def leerDatos():
    try:
        with open('finanzas2020.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            #next(reader)
            for fila in reader:
                finanzas.append(fila[0].split("\t"))

    except:
        print("No se encuentra el documento especificado o no tiene sus 12 columnas")

def verificarDatos():
    try:
        #Validamos que todos los datos son correctos
        for fila in range(1, len(finanzas)):
            for columna in range(len(finanzas[0])):
                if finanzas[fila][columna][0] == "-":
                    if finanzas[fila][columna][1:].isdigit() == False:
                        finanzas[fila][columna] = "0"
                else:
                    if finanzas[fila][columna][1:].isdigit() == False:
                        finanzas[fila][columna] = "0"


        # Agregamos los meses a una lista
        for i in range(12):
            meses.append(finanzas[0][i])

        # Registramos los gastos de todos los meses
        for fila in range(1, len(finanzas)):
            for columna in range(len(finanzas[0])):
                if int(finanzas[fila][columna]) < 0:
                    gastos[columna] += int(finanzas[fila][columna])
                if int(finanzas[fila][columna]) >= 0:
                    ingresos[columna] += int(finanzas[fila][columna])
        # Mostramos los datos
        for fila in finanzas:
            for columna in fila:
                print(columna, end=" ")
            print()

        masGastos = gastos[0]
        menosGastos = gastos[0]
        mesMenos = meses[0]
        mesMas = meses[0]
        for i in range(len(gastos)):
            if abs(gastos[i]) > abs(masGastos):
                masGastos = abs(gastos[i])
                mesMas = meses[i]
            if abs(gastos[i]) < abs(menosGastos):
                menosGastos = abs(gastos[i])
                mesMenos = meses[i]
        mediaGastos = round(statistics.mean(gastos), 3)
        gastoTotal = abs(sum(gastos))
        ingresoTotal = sum(ingresos)
        print()
        print("El mes que se ha gastado mas es: ", mesMas)
        print("El mes que se ha ahorrado mas es: ", mesMenos)
        print("La media de todos los gastos del año es: ", mediaGastos)
        print("Los gastos totales en todo el año suma: ", gastoTotal)
        print("El total de ingresos del año es: ", ingresoTotal)
        #print(gastos)
        #print(ingresos)
        #print(meses)
        #print(finanzas)
    except:
        print("Algo fallo")


finanzas = []
meses = []
gastos = [int() for i in range(12)]
ingresos = [int() for i in range(12)]

leerDatos()
verificarDatos()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nota: Uso unittest standard de Python. No explicare la mecánica de su uso, sólo como se aplica.]

El código, tal como está, no se presta para pruebas unitarias. Se pueden hacer, como está, pero serían costoso y complicado.

Cuando desarrollas usando pruebas unitarias tienes que dividir el código en funciones "unitarias", que hagan sólo una cosa. Por ejemplo, podemos extraer este código y ponerlo en su propia función:

```
def normalizar_datos(finanzas):
    # Validamos que todos los datos son correctos
    for fila in range(1, len(finanzas)):
        for columna in range(len(finanzas[0])):
            if finanzas[fila][columna][0] == "-":
                if finanzas[fila][columna][1:].isdigit() == False:
                    finanzas[fila][columna] = "0"
            else:
                if finanzas[fila][columna][1:].isdigit() == False:
                    finanzas[fila][columna] = "0"
```

Esta función tiene sólo un propósito: cambiar a cero todas las celdas que no sean númericas.

Hagamos una prueba unitaria sencilla, que pase una matriz valida y verifique que el resultado sea igual al original:

```
def test_normalizar(self):
    finanzas = [["2", "2"], ["1", "1"]]
    normalizar_datos((finanzas))
    self.assertEqual([["2", "2"], ["1", "1"]], finanzas)
```

y ... Oh!, cielos, la función falló:

```
Expected :[['2', '2'], ['1', '1']]
Actual   :[['2', '2'], ['0', '0']]
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raul/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/test/test_eval.py", line 774, in test_normalizar
    self.assertEqual([["2", "2"], ["1", "1"]], finanzas)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [['2', '2'], ['1', '1']] != [['2', '2'], ['0', '0']]

First differing element 1:
['1', '1']
['0', '0']

- [['2', '2'], ['1', '1']]
?                ^    ^

+ [['2', '2'], ['0', '0']]
?                ^    ^
```

El `self.assertEqual` chequea que dos expresiones sean iguales. Si no lo son, explica las diferencias.

Esto es bueno, pues ya pudimos detectar un error de lógica al primer intento. El error está en esta línea:

```
if finanzas[fila][columna][1:].isdigit() == False:
```

El error es que supone que el contenido de la celda tiene más de un caracter. El mismo error se presenta en el otro `if`.

#### Versión 2

Ahora que la prueba unitaria detectó un problema, lo corregimos, reemplazando el método de validación. Para validar que sea entero, aplicamos `int` sobre la celda, y si eso falla, colocamos un cero:

```
def normalizar_datos(finanzas):
    # Validamos que todos los datos son correctos
    for fila in range(1, len(finanzas)):
        for columna in range(len(finanzas[0])):
            try:
                _ = int(finanzas[fila][columna])
            except ValueError:
                finanzas[fila][columna] = 0
```

Corramos de nuevo la prueba unitaria:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ahora si está bien.

#### Desarrollos posteriores

Supongamos que este código será usado por otras personas, que pueden pasar parámetros incorrectos. Hagamos más pruebas unitarias, para chequear el comportamiento frente a una lista vacía, por ejemplo:

```
def test_normalizar_vacio(self):
    lista_vacia = []
    normalizar_datos(lista_vacia)
    self.assertEqual([], lista_vacia)
```

Cada problema que encuentres durante el desarrollo debe ser resuelto creando una prueba unitaria para ese caso específico. Así acumularas cientos de pruebas que te darán seguridad en la corrección del código.